# Spring Boot with Gradle - Issue with gradle build

Tags: java, spring, gradle

I am working on a project on Spring Boot with Gradle with multi projects[Parent & Child]
The issue is if run the command "gradle bootrun" it works fine and loads up the child projects instead if I use "gradle build" command the Jar that gets created does not have the child projects and running the Jar gives me noclassdeferror for the classes in the child project.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: can you paste your build.gradle, I believe this is because you did not get `org.springframework.boot` applied to the child projects.

Comment: This got resolved, the issue was with the way I was including the child components.
I was adding the 'configuration' while adding compile project statement.

Thanks a lot.